# Execute ClientSide before ServerSide in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

I am using ASP.NET 3.5.

When the user click on say btnSubmit I want to first execute some JavaScript code and then execute some C#/VB.NET code.

Is this possible? If so how would one do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ytf5t7k.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Server click handler called.";
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Runat="server" 
      OnClick="Button1_Click" 
        OnClientClick="return confirm('Ready to submit.');" 
        Text="Test Client Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Runat="server" text="" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the JavaScript execute and then call a web service with xmlhttprequest from the javascript

Answer (score 0):

There is onClientClick property - check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you simply add an onClick event all JS code is executed before the postback.

If the code is for validation and you decide you don't want to submit you can return false and it won't post.

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer guys!

To execute a function from code behind one would do this in VB.NET

```
 Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(blah blah) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "hiya", "Message()", True)
    lblLabel.Text = "Hello my name is Etienne!"

End Sub
```